# Отключить отправку форму по нажатию enter

Tags: jquery

Есть такая форма

```
<form action="/ajax/getProductList" name="filterForm" method="post" id="super_form">
<input type="text" name="searcg" value="">
</form>
```

Поиск работает как положено, но при нажатии на enter он переходит на страницу action. Как вообще отключить этот enter и на какое событие его посадить?

Comment: вы об этом читали когда изучали js https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault ?

Comment: Вам мой ответ подошел?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте такой JS код:

```js
$(document).keypress(
    function(event){
     if (event.which == '13') {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/ajax/getProductList" name="filterForm" method="post" id="super_form">
<input type="text" name="searcg" value="">
</form>
```